# "Remind Me Later" / "Quick Event" javascript solution?

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar, datepicker

I'm building an app that requires users to enter dates and times (obviously), and I always thought the [Remind Me Later](http://www.bdunagan.com/remind-me-later/) app and the [solution](http://images.macworld.com/images/article/2011/09/add-new-event-253307.jpg) Apple ended up making is a really great approach to the problem.  Is anyone aware of any good open source or for-pay solution that mirrors this?

Answer (score 0):

I found a nice solution thats close enough http://www.datejs.com/